# xfce4 boots into an xterm-like environment

Tags: xorg, mouse, xfce, xserver, xterm

Most probably after a forced reboot, whenever I load `xfce4` on my Ubuntu 13.04 I get this environment that looks like a buffed-up `xterm`, where I have an invisible mouse cursor: when I move around I cannot see a cursor but when it happens to go hover over a press-able button, the button changes color. I tried quitting that and starting X by `startx` but the only thing I got was a black screen. I proceeded as following:

- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling `xfce4` by:

  - `sudo apt-get remove --purge xfce4`
  - `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
- It did not work so I also tried:

  - `sudo apt-get remove --purge libxfce4util-common`
  - `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
- It also did not work so after removing `xfce4` I also tried removing and reinstalling xorg:

  - `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg`
  - `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg`
  - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
- Unfortunately this did not work either so I tried deleting also `~/.XAuthority*` but this did not work either.
- I also attempted to `startx` after reinstalling `xorg` and before installing `xfce4` but I was again getting just a black screen which makes very worried.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I tried logging in as `root`, as opposed to the regular user I was logging in before, and everything was working fine. This seemed to indicate that it was more of a configuration issue than an `xfce4` corruption.

Therefore I logged in again as the regular user that had the problem and deleted the configuration folder, after terminating `xfce4` process:

```
mv ~/.cache/sessions ~/.cache/sessions.bak
```

Then I restarted `xfce4` and everything was working great! Hope that proves helpful for some people.